# How to stop Content-Length header truncating short JSON snippets in a REST service

Tags: json, rest, coldfusion

For short JSON strings, if the `Content-Length` header is specified then the content is truncated and misses the last few characters. Is there a way to fix this:

Simple minimal example:

```
component restpath="test" rest = true {
  remote void function test(
    numeric len restargsource = "Path"
  )
    httpmethod = "GET"
    restpath   = "{len}"
    produces   = "application/json"
  {
    var value = {};
    var sb    = CreateObject( "java", "java.lang.StringBuffer" );
    for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++ )
      sb.append( 'a' );
    value[ sb.toString() ] = 1;

    var json  = SerializeJSON( value );

    restSetResponse(
      {
        "status"  = 200,
        "content" = json,
        "headers" = {
          "Content-Length" = Len( json.getBytes( 'UTF-8' ) ),
          "actual-value"   = json
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Trying

- `/test/1` through `/test/5` then the content returned is empty
- `/test/6` the content returned is `{`
- `/test/7` the content returned is `{"`
- `/test/8` the content returned is `{"a`
- `/test/9` the content returned is `{"aaaaaaaaa`
- `/test/10` the content returned is `{"aaaaaaaaaa"`
- `/test/11` the content returned is `{"aaaaaaaaaaa":`
- `/test/12` the content returned is `{"aaaaaaaaaaaa":1`
- `/test/13` the content returned is `{"aaaaaaaaaaaaa":1}` - finally a correct value!

The `actual-value` header consistently returns the entire JSON string and the `Content-Length` header is the length of the entire JSON string (i.e. longer than the length of the truncated contents but equal to the length of the `actual-value` header).

If the line which set the `Content-Length` header is commented out then the full JSON string is returned.

How can I get the `Content-Length` header not to truncate the contents?

*[Note: Currently running Apache 2.2, ColdFusion 11,0,03,292866 and Oracle JVM 1.8.0_25 (although I'm now in the process of upgrading Apache and applying the latest hotfixes to ColdFusion)]*

Comment: You can try setting a constant value such as `500` for `content-length`, and see what happens. Or may skip the `content-length` too.

Comment: `"Content-Length" = Max( 19, Len( json.getBytes( 'UTF-8' ) ) )` will cause the entire contents to be displayed (in this case) - however, I'm getting similar errors on some longer JSON strings (with more attributes in the objects) so I'm not sure an arbitrary length is the answer. As I said in the question, commenting out the `Content-Length` header will fix it. However, I would much prefer to report the correct length if possible.

Comment: Upgraded to Apache 2.4.17 and ColdFusion 11,0,07,296330 and it hasn't made any difference.

Answer (score -1):

Try to set the following response headers:

```
"headers" = {
  "Content-Type"   = "content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8"
  "Content-Length" = Len(json)
}
```